# Hibernte Error => EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, api

I try to insert a new object in my Databse from Spring Boot API, but I have an error when I call my PostMapping

Controller

```
    @PostMapping("/users/{userId}/vehicules")
    public ResponseEntity<String> insertVehicule(@PathVariable Integer userId, @RequestBody Vehicule body) {
        Utilisateur utilisateur = UserRepository.getOne(userId);
        VehiculeRepository.save(new Vehicule(VehiculeRepository.findAll().size()+1,body.getMarque(),body.getModele(),body.getImmatriculation(),
                body.getMiseEnCirculation(),body.getNombreKilometre(),utilisateur,body.getComposants()));
        return new ResponseEntity("Hello",HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Class Vehicule

```
public class Vehicule   {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id = null;

    @Column(name="marque")
    private String marque = null;

    @Column(name="modele")
    private String modele = null;

    @Column(name="immatriculation")
    private String immatriculation = null;

    @Column(name="miseEnCirculation")
    private String miseEnCirculation = null;

    @Column(name="nombreKilometre")
    private String nombreKilometre = null;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private Utilisateur user = null;

    @Transient
    private List<Composant> composants = null;
}
```

Thanks for help
Have a good day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the id inside the controller, JPA will try to update it instead of save the entity, then you get the exception as it doesnt exists. JPA will generate the id in case of creation.

```
@PostMapping("/users/{userId}/vehicules")
public ResponseEntity<String> insertVehicule(@PathVariable Integer userId, @RequestBody Vehicule body) {
    Utilisateur utilisateur = UserRepository.getOne(userId);
    VehiculeRepository.save(new Vehicule(null,body.getMarque(),body.getModele(),body.getImmatriculation(),
            body.getMiseEnCirculation(),body.getNombreKilometre(),utilisateur,body.getComposants()));
    return new ResponseEntity("Hello",HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: When I change setId by Null I have a PK violation

Comment: what is your database ? how do you declare the primary key ? Make sure the id column is decalred as primary key with auto increment. Depending of the database, you should use GenerationType.IDENTITY or SEQUENCE

Comment: Yes it's my database with Postgre. The tables are generate automatically when I run my api. The ID is declared as primary key, but I think don't have auto increment. But I think it's not possible to update colunm properties after generation